# How to transform CommaDelimitedList parameter to build ARNs in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a input parameter that is a list of role names:

```
Parameters:
  UserRoles:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
```

Now I want to use these roles in a policy document principal. If it would be only 1 Role, I would do:

```
        Principal:
          AWS:
            - !Join
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
                - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                - ':role/'
                - !Ref UserRole
```

But now I want to do that for a variable number of roles. So I need some sort of "Fn::Map" function on the list of strings allowing me to transform the role names into Arns.

Is that possible?

Comment: I have a similar need, but mapping from an array to a set of resources. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the Cloudformation Join function with a CommaDelimitedList Parameter to build IAM ARNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925850/using-the-cloudformation-join-function-with-a-commadelimitedlist-parameter-to-bu)

Answer (score 2):

There's no immediate solution using CloudFormation native constructs, however you can build one by using a macro.

You can find a full example below. In summary, the solution has two components:

1. A CloudFormation stack which creates a macro for the string manipulation you require
2. A CloudFormation stack which deploys your resources. This stack consumes the macro deployed by the first stack

The example below addresses the direct question being asked here, however it should be useful to the general reader who wants to do custom string manipulation.

---

**Building a custom macro for string manipulation**

The following template creates a macro backed by a lambda function. When the macro is invoked, the lambda function is executed.

The macro (and thus the lambda), takes as inputs the list of comma separated roles (e.g. `role1,role2`) and the AWS account ID, and returns the formatted IAM roles (e.g. `[arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/role1,arn:aws:iam::12345678910:role/role2]`).

This is the full template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  TransformExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: ['logs:*']
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
  TransformFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import traceback
          def handler(event, context):
              response = {
                  "requestId": event["requestId"],
                  "status": "success"
              }
              try:
                  role_names = event["params"]["RoleNames"]
                  account_id = str(event["params"]["AccountId"])

                  role_formatter = lambda role : "arn:aws:iam::" + account_id + ":role/" + role
                  formatted_roles = list(map(role_formatter,role_names))

                  response["fragment"] = formatted_roles

              except Exception as e:
                  traceback.print_exc()
                  response["status"] = "failure"
                  response["errorMessage"] = str(e)
              return response
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Role: !GetAtt TransformExecutionRole.Arn
  TransformFunctionPermissions:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt TransformFunction.Arn
      Principal: 'cloudformation.amazonaws.com'
  Transform:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Macro
    Properties:
      Name: 'FormatIamRoles'
      Description: Provides various string processing functions
      FunctionName: !GetAtt TransformFunction.Arn
```

---

**Consuming a custom macro for string manipulation**

The following template illustrates how the custom macro previously deployed can be used for creating a policy for an S3 bucket.

The template takes as inputs the name of an S3 bucket, and a comma separated list of IAM role names.

The macro (see usage of `'Fn::Transform'`), takes as inputs the comma separated list of IAM role names and the AWS account id. It returns the formatted list of IAM roles and uses it to create the policy for the specified S3 bucket.

```
Parameters:
  UserRoles:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "role1,role2"
  MyBucket:
    Type: String
    Default: my-bucket
Resources:
  MyBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: MyRoleAllow
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS: 
                'Fn::Transform':
                  - Name: 'FormatIamRoles'
                    Parameters:
                      RoleNames: !Ref UserRoles
                      AccountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${MyBucket}/*
```

on completion of the stack deployment, you'll find that the IAM roles were added to the bucket:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. this is possible in plain cloudformation, but it's hard and hacky. You'll need to abuse almost every cloudformation function you have available.

Consider the following steps:

- First add a parameter and ask for a comma seperated input
- Right pad the parameters with commas to force empty values and use !Select and !Not to figure out how many are not empty
- Then set a condition for every value that is set (ie. is there one item in the list? Two? Three?)
- Then for every condition that is true, you can use !Select to find the value in your parameter list

Here's an example. Forgive me for not splitting everything into pure YAML, I kept the JSON to keep it at least somewhat readeable, but tools like PyCharm will complain even though AWS thinks it's fine:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  MyCommaSeparatedParameters:
    Type: String
    Default: FirstParam,SecondParam,ThirdParam

Conditions:
  # See the additional commas? That's to prevent erroring out when there's less than 3 items in the list
  ConditionParam0:    !Not [!Equals [!Select [0, !Split [',', !Sub '${MyCommaSeparatedParameters},,,']], '']]
  ConditionParam1:    !Not [!Equals [!Select [1, !Split [',', !Sub '${MyCommaSeparatedParameters},,,']], '']]
  ConditionParam2:    !Not [!Equals [!Select [2, !Split [',', !Sub '${MyCommaSeparatedParameters},,,']], '']]

Resources:
  Ec2InstanceIamDefaultPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: "SomeRandomPolicy"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
          - "s3:GetObject"
          Resource:
          - !If
            - ConditionParam0
            - !Sub
                - "arn:aws:s3:::vopak-infra-automations/${param}"
                - param: !Select [0, !Split [',', !Sub '${MyCommaSeparatedParameters},,,']]
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
          - !If
            - ConditionParam1
            - !Sub
                - "arn:aws:s3:::vopak-infra-automations/${param}"
                - param: !Select [1, !Split [',', !Sub '${MyCommaSeparatedParameters},,,']]
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
          - !If
            - ConditionParam2
            - !Sub
                - "arn:aws:s3:::vopak-infra-automations/${param}"
                - param: !Select [2, !Split [',', !Sub '${MyCommaSeparatedParameters},,,']]
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

You probably need a Condition attribute with a set of the separate roles you wish to create, instead of the list based creation I did here.

Comment: This implies creating one condition for each value in the comma delimited list, right? It isn't flexible

Comment: No, it's not flexible at all. It's not a good solution, the redeeming argument is that it is purely cloudformation based without requiring a lambda macro.