# Cloudformation: Create array of log ARNs from comma delimited list of log names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have parameter `LogNames` - comma delimited list of log names:

```
  LogNames:
    Type: String
    Default: >-
      /aws/my-custom-log-1,/aws/my-custom-log-1
```

I want to use it in the IAM policy definition - `Resource` field:

```
Resource:
  <array of allowed log ARNs created from LogNames parameter>
```

Any idea how to use functions e.g. Split, Join, Sub, ... to generate correct array of log ARNs? Single log ARN have syntax:

```
- !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:${LogName}:*'
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475459/3390419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its **not possible** without a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The only way to do it without these, is to hardcode your `region` and `accountid` and use combo of Split, Join, Sub:

```
Parameters:
  LogNames:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: >-
      /aws/my-custom-log-1,/aws/my-custom-log-2,/aws/my-custom-log-3

Resource:
          !Split:
            - ","
            - !Sub
                - "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:234234234234:log-group:${logname}"
                - logname: !Join
                          - ",arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:234234234234:log-group:"
                          - !Ref LogNames
```

Comment: Yes, it is a problem. I made it semi dynamic (max 4 log names), because I don't want to have additional resources for that. My use case: https://github.com/monitoringartist/grafana-cross-account-cloudwatch-access/blob/bfcddf7feb6ed00677e162e45c246fcbb1cb81f9/cloudformation-grafana-cross-account-cloudwatch-access.yaml#L148-L180